# logarithmic derivative of $x^{e^{(x^2+\cos x)}}$

Tags: integration, derivatives, logarithms

I'm having a hard time taking the derivative of $$f(x) = x^{e^{(x^2+cosx)}}.$$
I'm aware that I have to take the logarithm of both sides.
$$\ln(y) = \ln({x^{e^{(x^2+\cos x)}}}) = \ln(x)\cdot e^{(x^2+\cos x)}$$
Which I tried to untie, so lets start:
First I use the product rule:
$$\frac{1}{y}\cdot y' = \frac{1}{x}\cdot e^{(x^2+\cos x)}+\ln(x)\cdot e^{(x^2+\cos x)}$$
Next the power rule:
$$\frac{1}{y}\cdot y' = \frac{1}{x}\cdot e^{(x^2+\cos x)}+\ln(x)*e^{(x^2+cosx)}\cdot x^2+\cos x\cdot e^{(x^2+\cos x)-1}$$
And last the chain rule:
$$\frac{1}{y}\cdot y' = \frac{1}{x}\cdot e^{(x^2+\cos x)}+\ln(x)\cdot e^{(x^2+cosx)}\cdot x^2+\cos x\cdot e^{(x^2+\cos x)-1}\cdot 2x-\sin x$$
Then I bring the y to the right:
$$y' = y\cdot {(\frac{1}{x}\cdot e^{(x^2+\cos x)}+\ln(x)\cdot e^{(x^2+\cos x)}\cdot x^2+\cos x\cdot e^{(x^2+\cos x)-1}\cdot 2x-\sin x)}$$
And exchange y with the term:
$$y' = x^{e^{(x^2+\cos x)}}\cdot {(\frac{1}{x}\cdot e^{(x^2+\cos x)}+\ln(x)\cdot e^{(x^2+\cos x)}\cdot x^2+\cos x\cdot e^{(x^2+\cos x)-1}\cdot 2x-\sin x)}$$

This is extremely overwhelming for me and I have absolutely no clue if this is right, I looked in to the result of wolfram and It doesn't seem to be correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your mistake is trying to use the power rule on a funtion that's not of the form $x^n$. Also, you should leave a $\frac{d}{dx}()$ around parts of the equation you still haven't differentiated - it will make your formulas much clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right until writing
$$
\ln f(x)=\ln x\cdot e^{x^2+\cos x}.
$$
The rest, I'm afraid, is completely wrong.

You can differentiate both sides using the product rule:
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=(\ln x)' \cdot e^{x^2+\cos x} + \ln x\cdot (e^{x^2+\cos x})'
$$
Let's split the problem, now: what's $(e^{x^2+\cos x})'$? Here you can apply the chain rule:
$$
(e^{x^2+\cos x})'=(2x-\sin x)e^{x^2+\cos x}.
$$
Therefore you have
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{x}e^{x^2+\cos x}+\ln x\cdot(2x-\sin x)e^{x^2+\cos x}
$$

Comment: Now I see it $e^{x^2+cosx}$ is the chain rule not the power rule. So the form of $f'(g(x))*g'(x)$ where $f(x) = e^{g(x)}$ and $g(x)=x^2+cosx$, right ?

Comment: @Boshy753 Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, helped me a lot. Now I see that my whole thing is completely rubbish and ten times more complicated than the task really is. :)

Comment: @Boshy753 Remember that the power rule applies only to functions of the form $f(x)=x^k$, where $k$ is *constant*.

Comment: Yes I see that this was the biggest mistake in my calculation which made the thing utterly confusing. I have one remaining question, if the task was to find the derivative, in order to give a proper solution do I have to multiply $f(x)$ to the right term, so $f'(x)$ is alone on the left side or can I leave it as it is?

Comment: @Boshy753 Yes, that's the last step.

Answer (score 1):

Set $\large u=e^{(x^2+\cos x)}$. Then $\large u'=e^{(x^2+\cos x)}\cdot(2x-\sin x)$.

$\large f(x)=x^u=e^{u\ln x}$.

So, $\large f'(x)=e^{u\ln x}\cdot(u' \ln x+\dfrac{u}{x})=x^u\cdot(u' \ln x+\dfrac{u}{x})$.

Now substitute back.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a way to keep track of what you've done so far, and apply the chain rule in steps. Let's start where you did:
$$
      \ln (y) = \ln (x) e^{x^{2}+\cos x}
$$
Then the product rule and chain rule give
$$
\begin{align}
      \frac{y'}{y} & = \left[\frac{d}{dx}\ln x\right] e^{x^{2}+\cos x}
    + \ln(x) \left[\frac{d}{dx}e^{x^{2}+\cos(x)}\right] \\
        & = \frac{1}{x}e^{x^{2}+\cos x}+\ln(x)e^{x^{2}+\cos x}\frac{d}{dx}(x^{2}+\cos x) \\
      & = \frac{1}{x}e^{x^{2}+\cos x}+\ln(x) e^{x^{2}+\cos x}(2x-\sin x).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Okay thank you very much, I from now one will write it the way you have, it suddenly makes the whole task ten times easier.